# Can i integrate Blender with Phanthom Omni

Tags: python, blender

I have some project about game programming, which have to use blender with phanthom ,Don't know possible to do it

Comment: Do you mean Phantom Omni? If so, what does an input device have to do with a rendering program?

If not, I can't find anything about Phanthom on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean Phantom Omni, the haptic feedback device, and you mean Blender, the rendering program, then I don't see any reason why you can't use the API for both of them in a program, together to make a game.

In short, if your questions means what I think it does, of course.

Comment: thank isaac, and i want to know more about use phanthom omni in blender game engine